# Meteor Iron Router - Router.go callback possible?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've got a link that I want the user to press. When they press it, the router will go to a certain template and then run Smoothscroll.js code to animate and scroll down to the anchor tag.

```
      //When the user clicks on the link to get to the #contact anchor...
      //The code below does not work.
      Router.go('index');
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#contact').offset().top
      }, 1200);
```

`Router.go('index')` works just fine.

```
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#contact').offset().top
      }, 1200);
```

Works as well by itself on the index template.

But when I try to run them together, the router goes to index, but the scrolling does not work.

Any idea how I can do this?

**EDIT**

This is what I have for the latest Meteor 1.0+ and a path like `/#contact`

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'index'
});

Router.onAfterAction(function() {
    var self = this;
    // always start by resetting scroll to top of the page
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    // if there is a hash in the URL, handle it
    if (this.params.hash) {
        // now this is important : Deps.afterFlush ensures that iron-router rendering
        // process has finished inserting the current route template into DOM so we
        // can manipulate it via jQuery, if you skip this part the HTML element you
        // want to scroll to might not yet be present in the DOM (this is probably
        // why your code fails in the first place)
        Tracker.afterFlush(function() {

            if (typeof $("#" + self.params.hash).offset() != "undefined"){
                var scrollTop = $("#" + self.params.hash).offset().top;

                $("html,body").animate({
                    scrollTop: scrollTop
                });

            }

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're doing something fancy you probably don't want to use `Router.go` and instead let iron-router manage routing on anchor click as it normally does.

As far as scrolling to an element is concerned, this is the `onAfterAction` hook I'm using, it supports any route and any hash (`/anyroute#anyhash`).

```
Router.onAfterAction(function() {
  // always start by resetting scroll to top of the page
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
  var hash=this.params.hash;
  // if there is a hash in the URL, handle it
  if (hash) {
    // now this is important : Tracker.afterFlush ensures that iron-router
    // rendering process has finished inserting the current route template
    // into DOM so we can manipulate it via jQuery, if you skip this part
    // the HTML element you want to scroll to might not yet be present in
    // the DOM (this is probably why your code fails in the first place)
    Tracker.afterFlush(function() {
      var element=$("#"+hash);
      var scrollTop = element.offset().top;
      $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTop
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Cool, I'll give this a shot.

Where do you find `Deps.autoFlush`? I can't find any mention of it in documentation. It's definitely not in the Meteor Manual.

Comment: Hi just wondering what this would look like for latest meteor 1.0.2.1? Also I am getting "undefined" on the $(#.. call.

Comment: FYI created Meteor 1.0 version here and posted as iron-router issue: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1171

Comment: @aginsburg, I've updated my OP to highlight the code for the latest Meteor.